# Are there any alternatives to PRINT_MODE:2D that is compatible with Stonesense on macOS?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, macos

DFhack comes with Stonesense pre-installed. But when I run the stonesense command from the Dfhack console, I get this error message (when I use PRINT_MODE:STANDARD):

```
The current print mode is not suported
Change PRINT_MODE in init.txt to 2D or a similar choice
```

The problem is, I am using a Mac, And MacOS does not support 2D mode. I have tried using PRINT_MODE:TEXT, but the DFhack console will not launch.

I have also tried FRAME_BUFFER, but I get the unsupported print mode error.

Comment: Without really knowing much about the game, what about `PRINT_MODE:STANDARD`? https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Installation#Mac

Comment: I am using STANDARD, That's when I got the error message.